# How to build a drag and drop script like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have recently been using sitecake, I like the drag and drop interface of it for the content editor. Try the demo on their site for the visual editor.
I am wondering how can I build a 'local' script like this for my managing and creating articles for my site.

What I need is the drag and drop options like this and a button which onClick outputs the html of the current display.

I have been looking into jQuery DND, draggable and droppable, HTML5 contentEditable and edit-inplace.

But unfortunately, nothing yet.

Can someone help me with this? Or altest point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're really going to make us find their site, and their demo? Where's the link!?

Comment: @BZink thanks for your time, I just didn't wanted to offend the developer of sitecake. But I see the Dev. is already on the page here. the link to the site is : sitecake.com they have the link to the demo on front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out jQueryUI [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable) and maybe even [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable).

Droppable is certainly capable of what you're asking. All you would need to do is specify drop points, which is what sitecake does.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what about getting the html code of the final arrange? Do you know how to get that?

Comment: You don't need the HTML code, all you need to keep track of, which would be done through AJAX when a drop is made, is where an element was dropped.
You have to create "Zones" or "Drop Points" and any time you drop an element into that drop point, you send an update to the server through AJAX, which will store the result in the database.

Comment: thanks mate thats a good tip. Maybe I need to find a way to create a 'drop point' dynamically tracking if a dropable object was dropped in a droppable zone. I would surely like them to be resizable too

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer behind SiteCake. The first version of SiteCake was developed based on GWT and jQuery/jQueryUI Droppable and Draggable. The current version is powered by GWT and GWT-DnD library.
I am not sure I understand clearly your question about getting the html code.

Comment: Greeting @NikolaIvancevic
I must say I love your interface at SiteCake. I am just trying to find a way to create pages that I can put in a rich text editor and it maintains the layout created while drag and drop, for my experiment. I don't want to involve server-side programming for this purpose.

Comment: How are you going to save any page content or layout change if there's no server-side programming (service)?

Comment: I just want to save the page content in a text file on my local system. That I can do manually if I have the <HTML> code.
Thanks

Comment: After any DOM manipulation, for example, using jQuery Draggable/Droppable to drag&drop a piece of page, you could use innerHtml (or jQuery html method, e.g. $('body').html()) to obtain desired HTML code.

Comment: that is awesome thank you :)
Can you also tell me how to drag and drop form elements like textarea, image, videos, etc into the droppable zones and just show buttons like your's?
Thanks you very much for helping out. Its amazing to learn to do such cool things myself :)

Comment: What I meant was if I create a dock like yours and have buttons for dropping various things like editable textareas etc, how can I trigger the code?